# DVD VOB to AVI - Can't hear sound

Tags: windows-8, dvd, ripping, ubuntu-12.10

I have DVD that plays fine in cheap Home DVD Player, but I'm trying to convert it to files I can play on my computer.

When I try to play the DVD itself on my computer, there is no audio, but audio plays fine in the dvd player that's hooked up to my TV.

I've tried playing the DVD on Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10, but no sound.

I've tried converting the VOB files to AVI xvid, with DVD:Rip and handbrake too, but those files never include the sound track along with the video.

If you look at the file system on the DVD, the "AUDIO-TS" folder is empty.

If you look at the properties of one of the vob files it says the audio is:
codec: DVD LPCM
Channels: Stereo
Sample rate: 48000 Hz
Bitrate: 1536 kbps

Any suggestions as to how I might successfully convert these files to a format I can view AND HEAR on my computer?

Edit: With help I've discovered that the audio properties aren't actually stereo (as the VOB claims); only the left channel has audio. Perhaps if I could change the VOB files meta data to say mono instead of stereo and it would play fine?

Edit2: For some reason, recent operating systems won't play audio out of my laptop's left speaker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1075405

So, the audio was there, but since it only plays out of the left channel, I didn't hear it.

Comment: Install VLC and use it to open the DVD or VIDEO_TS folder - does it play with sound properly? AUDIO_TS is typically empty for video DVDs; it's present for compatibility reasons (with audio DVDs I guess).

Comment: I have VLC installed, and it too doesn't play the sound by default, but I just right-clicked on the Audio Channel setting, and selected "left" (instead of "stereo") and I can hear it now. Still need to figure out how to convert it so it has audio...

Comment: So it has a mono track? Also, do you *have* to convert? If you're simply looking to play back on your PC, why not just dump the VIDEO_TS folder or create an ISO image of the disc that you can mount and play? (Of course if it's a commercial DVD then you'll need something to get around [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System).)

Comment: Well, this is just one of the instructional videos I've purchased. I've converted all the others to AVI and would like to do it to this one too so I can add it to my playlist easily. I'd hate to have to set the audio each time I play the video....

Comment: If it's really a mono track guess you could duplicate it and create a fake stereo track, but I'm no expert at audio editing.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to specify it is stereo, but it is actually just left. If I could correct that meta-data some how, maybe it would work by default. On one of my conversion attempts, I tried to convert the audio to mono, but it turned out ugly - the whole video was much slower with deep, deep voices.

Comment: Still, Handbrake etc. should have retained the track, even if it was mono. There might be something else that's messed up, but I'm not sure what it could be. Can you run MediaInfo on the VOBs and include the results in your question?

Comment: Well, your suggestions have been helpful. Thank you.